# Redirect back after login

Tags: authentication

i need to force login for all visit to my web site, for this reason when a visitor shows a page i redirect him to login page and only if he logins or registers to  my web site i redirect him another time to the original page he visited. the problem is in the  last step, i'm not able to redirect to original page because url is not saved in history before first redirect

for first redirect i use for not users

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = '/login-guest';
</script>
```

for second redirect, after login or registration i use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
history.back(-1);
</script>
```

i think i need to add a script to add url to history before first redirect

tx, best regards

Answer (score 0):

you could try using HTML5 sessionStorage to store the users webpage in the first script and then retrieve it in the second script

edit: now with code:

edit 2: now with onpageload

because of this onload() you cannot move the checkPage function to the body

Page 1:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
 function checkPage(){
    if(sessionStorage.visited != 1){
        sessionStorage.startingPage = document.URL;
        window.location.href = 'sessionstorage2.html';
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload='checkPage()'>
 text or something

 <br><br>

 <script>
 function reset(){
    sessionStorage.visited = 0;
 }
 </script>
 <button onclick='reset()'>Reset Function</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function return(){
    window.location.href = sessionStorage.startingPage;
    sessionStorage.visited = 1;
}
</script>
<p><button onclick="return()" type="button">Return to Page 1</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, tx for your reply but is it possibile not use button to save url? (i mean do it in automatic way) and add it not in head but in body? tx

Comment: Yes it is you can use the body onload event to redirect automaticly and i have to checkif you can do it in the body let me get back to you on that (im at school now)